# Pastespecial is not working although paste does

Tags: excel, vba, paste

Activesheet.pastespecial is not working as it should be. Activesheet.paste gives me the result but i also need formatting.

```
Sub Show()

Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Activeworkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("A1:F30")
Rng.Select
Rng.Copy
Activeworkbook.Close

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "Dashboard" & NewFile
With ActiveSheet
.Range("A1").Activate
.Range("A1").Select
.Pastespecial Paste:=XlPasteAll **<-------**

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Should be Selection.Pastespecial Paste:=XlPasteAll  Just tested on my end and it does bring over formatting.

Comment: BTW, you can replace the five last lines with `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:= xlPasteAll`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify where to paste.

```
With ActiveSheet
.Range("A1").Pastespecial Paste:=XlPasteAll **<-------**

End With
```

Comment: did you remove the **<-------** ?
I tested and it is working for me

Answer (score 0):

Don't close the workbook before pasting and you should be fine. I have never done such a thing myself, but it looks like after closing you can only paste values. I tried to paste formatting and an error occured.